# how to get the address of a winner in lottery decentarlized lottery application

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I created a lottery application in solidity. All things are working fine but I want to add this feature that when the winner is selected it should return me the address of winner as well.

What can i do for this? Any help will be appreciated, thanks. Here is my solidity code.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Lottery_Application {

    address public manager;
    address payable[] public participants;

    constructor() {
        manager=msg.sender;
    }

    receive() external payable {
        require(msg.value>=1 ether);
        participants.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function getbalance() public view returns(uint) {
        require(msg.sender==manager);
        return address(this).balance;

    }

    function random() public view returns(uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty,block.timestamp,participants.length)));
    }

    function selectwinner() public returns(address) {
        require(msg.sender==manager);
        require(participants.length>=3);
        uint r=random();
        address payable winner;
        uint index=r% participants.length;
        winner=participants[index];
        winner.transfer(getbalance());
        winner=address(msg.sender);
        return winner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

State changing functions are unable to return anything. You could do this two ways.

1. Create and use events.

`event WinnerSelected(address winner)`

At the end of your winnerSelect function,
`emit WinnerSelected(winner)`.

2. Create a global variable to store recent winner.
   `address public recentWinner`

At the end of your winnerSelect function,
`recentWinner = winner`.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a public variable and pass the winner array in that variable.
Look at the code below and pay attention to the lines that are commented.

For Example.

`SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT pragma solidity ^0.8.9;`

```
contract lotteryProject
{
address public  owner;
address public addressofwinner;   //public variable to store the address of winner

address payable []  public  part;
receive() external payable virtual {}
uint value;
constructor()
{
    owner=msg.sender;
}

function depositEthers() public payable{
    require( msg.value==10 ether , " 2Ethers are required to participate in this lottery: ");
    // participants[msg.sender]= value;
    part.push(payable(msg.sender));
}

function totalDeposits()public view returns(uint)
{   
    require (msg.sender== owner, "Only owner is 
        authorized to chech the total deposits");
    return address(this).balance;
}
//ethers deposition has been completed 
//now ethers randomization is reamang 

function random()public view returns (uint) 
{
    require(msg.sender==owner);
    return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.prevrandao,
         block.timestamp , part.length)));

}

function winner()public
{
    require(msg.sender==owner);
    require(part.length>=3);

    uint r = random();
     
    uint index = r % part.length;
    address payable  won ;
    won= part[index]; 
    addressofwinner=won;              //passing winner's address in the public variable 
    won.transfer(totalDeposits());
    part= new address payable[](0);   //TO empty the array after assigning a winner
     } 
   }
```